# When can I start using lollipops?

Tags: candy-box-2

I know about lollipops and what they do.

I also know about what the sorceress, mill, and wishing well do.

When are they unlocked for me to start using my lollipops?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the farm and the wishing well after you get through the desert.

You should be able to access the sorceress after you have crossed the bridge successfully.